# writedump shows more than loop over a structure

Tags: coldfusion

My client wants a list of every item with the name of the categories it belongs to in each appropriate column.

```
<cfscript>
   arr = ArrayNew(1);
   arr[1] = '';
   arr[2] = 'category B';
   stc["Item One"] = arr;
   arr[1] = 'category A';
   arr[2] = '';
   stc["Item Two"] = arr;
   arr[1] = 'category A';
   arr[2] = 'category B';
   stc["Item Three"] = arr;
   writedump(stc);
   for (element in stc) {
     WriteOutput(element & '<br>');
     // The next line produces: 
     // Object of type class java.lang.String cannot be used as an array
     for (i=1; i<=ArrayLen(element); i+=1) {
     }
   }
</cfscript>
```

Q: How do I get to the arrays inside of each element?

Comment: Will you eventually be retrieving this information from a database?

Answer (score 7):

In your example, you are using a `for ... in` loop to iterate through the **keys** of the struct, not the values. This can be a bit confusing, for the same syntax with an array will iterate through the **elements**.

In your code, you have placed the key string into `element`, which isn't the array. This is the reason why the error `Object of type class java.lang.String cannot be used as an array` is produced.

As RRK has answered, to access the value in the struct you need to use the syntax `struct[keyOfItem]`.

```
//Loop keys in the struct
for (key in stc) {
    writeOutput(key & '<br>');
    //Loop items in the array
    for(element in stc[key]){
        writeOutput(element & '<br>');
    }
}
```

Comment: Was about to say the same thing :)

Answer (score 3):

You can access the arrays inside using `[]` representation.

`stc[element]` This will get you the array.

```
for (i=1; i<=ArrayLen(stc[element]); i+=1) {
    writedump(stc[element][i]);
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://www.trycf.com/gist/168d777d0955fdaa198ac3e64374feb9/acf2018?theme=monokai)

Comment: Actually writeoutput(stc[element][i]);

Comment: Sure, if you want to get each individual values inside array.

Comment: ... or if you don't need the index for anything, use an array loop `for (value in stc[element]) { writedump(value); }`